# Handling multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a music mixer but I don't know how I can create multiple objects.

Since I can't make a dynamic object name like in a loop I don't know how to handle this

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '.regua div[regua-item="index-0"]',
    scrollParent : true
});

wavesurfer.load('link.mp3');
wavesurfer.play();
```

The problem is I can't call this more than **once** because it would rewrite the link from `wavesurfer.load`

Like this:

```
wavesurfer.load('link_2.mp3') // once i load another music this one will be destroyed
wavesurfer.load('link_3.mp3')
```

What is the solution here?

Comment: You probably need to add different WaveSurfers to different containers.
You can also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126035/wavesurfer-js-multiple-instances-on-page) for a more complex example.

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic name? Can't you just create an array of objects?

Comment: i tried creating an array but i didn't go as planed

Comment: An array is probably the way to go. If you show us what you did for that perhaps we can help.

Comment: Also: how many files do you need loaded at the same time? Is it just two (to cross-fade) or many more (like an entire library for mixing many tracks at the same time)?

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try would be to use a [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) with an if statement that detects to see if the wavesurfer is done by using [.ended()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_ended.asp). Something like this:

```
let musicInterval = setInterval(function(){
  if(wavesurfer.ended()){
    //Your code


    // this is to clear the interval, if that is what you want.
    clearInterval(musicInterval)
  }
},100)
```

Comment: yea im using something like that for a play/pause button but i need to add multiple objects to play together like a dj mixer.

Comment: The problem is that OP needs to instantiate multiple concurrent `WaveSurfer`s.